# Send JavaScript data to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `JS` code where I can capture, through an input button, the `filename` from the file(txt) I selected. How could I possibly send this filename to another view(I know I can't do this directly) and print it there(using puts, for example or any other method).

The **JS** code:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('file').value;
   if (fullPath) {
      var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
      var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
      if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(1);
      }
   }
   if(passAll === true){
   console.log(filename);
   }
}
```

You can `disconsider` the last **if** and `concider` just the `console.log`

Comment: *"I have a JS code..."* this would be a good place to start by posting the code. Then maybe explain your intent a bit more.

Comment: Sure I will do it

Comment: @user315139192111315 are you simply to pass information to a new view, or persist the data in your database and show that data in a following view?

Comment: Persist it, I would be really happy if you could help me with it or anybody

Comment: Do you have a model which contains a filename as it's attribute?

Comment: Ahm... no I didn't know exatly what to do after what I did up there

Comment: I saw things about Ajax but didn't get it very well and all my models were generated automaticaly (user, ability, role)

Comment: Shoul I create a, for example, `history.rb` and do a `class StoreFilename < ActiveRecord::Base` then `attribute :filename, :string` ?

Comment: You say the models were generated automatically, was this through a scaffold command? It seems that you don't have the most basic grasp of Rails. You should post your Rails code.

Comment: A generated them via Devise and no, I dont have any scaffold :)

Comment: I didn't generate any scaffold until now cuz at the moment it wasn't necessary. Looks like it is now